# Advanced Search returns contacts with current memberships even though Current Member set to "No"

Tags: search, smartgroups, search-results, advanced-search

When using *Advanced Search* and *'Display Results As'* is set to *"Contacts"*, I assumed that if I selected *"No"* for *'Current Member'*, it would not include contacts that had at least one active/current membership, but it turns out I was wrong. (We try our best to only keep one membership per contact, but there are sometimes circumstances where we have to keep multiple, e.g. one through a family member, where one is expired while the other one is still active.)

Is this a but or a design opinion difference?

If I set *'Display Results As'* to *"Memberships"*, then yeah, I'd expect that it'll pull the non-current memberships even though the contact may have another, active, one.

What's the easiest way to pull contacts with non-current memberships? One way I can think of is to create two smart groups: 1) Current members; 2) Non-current members ... then a 3rd one with criteria *"is part of Non-Current Members and is not part of Current Members"* ... seems like a super complex way to achieve a pretty basic use case for a CRM (i.e., how can I easily identify and send a mailing to non-current users, e.g. for a membership drive campaign).

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do that with SearchKit.  Look for contacts 'with (required)' a non-current membership and 'without' a current membership.

Comment: Thank you - I'm unable to install it - getting an "Entity not loadedGrant" error. We don't use CiviGrant, and I don't feel compelled installing it just to enable SearchKit. I submitted a bug to the SearchKit lab, but it hasn't been accepted yet for some reason. I'll keep trying.

Comment: You don't need CiviGrant enabled for SearchKit but there was a bug in that area when Grants were moved from core to a core extension.  Are you on the latest version?  If not, upgrading may help.

Comment: Thanks again. I'm on CiviCRM 5.52.2, SearchKit 5.52.2